# Closing a window after Header location mailto

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm searching for a good thing to do after doing a redirect to a mailto after clicking on a link to send mail. Is there any good way to do close, or something clever to do after the user "received" the option to send the mail?

Only code up to here is the Header location one (with code to get email, that isn't really pertinent)

```
Header("Location: mailto:mail@email.com");
```

As stated in the comment below:

> My bad, that was a bit dumb. I thought
>   for a moment that mailto opened a new
>   window, but in fact I forgot the new
>   _blank window :/ Sorry for this question..

Comment: If you want a link to send mail, why not just `<a href="mailto:...">`? Once you issue a header redirect, you can't do much else to the browser as it'll probably be off loading the new url and shutting down the link to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't open a window in the first place, just do a simple:

```
<a href="mailto:mail@email.com">click me</a>
```

Or is there a need to do this via header?

Comment: My bad, that was a bit dumb. I thought for a moment that mailto opened a new window, but in fact I forgot the new _blank window :/
Sorry for this question..

Answer (score 0):

@[Mark B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b) or @[yoshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/697154/yoshi) I would always use the `Header` way instead of `href`. The header can be stored in a MailHandler.php file and so the email address is hidden and more protected by fishing email - addresses.

MailHandler.php:

```php
<?php
   Header("Location: mailto:mail@email.com");
?>
```

Sorry. I am not allowed to add a comment, so I have to do it as new answer